# become or becomes in this context

Tags: word-order

Which to say, *become* or *becomes*?

> After millions of years, fish began to grow teeth and **becomes/become** like the fish of today.

Comment: . . . fish began to grow teeth and **became** like the fish of today.

Comment: I suggested **became** which is the past tense. The present tense **become** would be used in a journalistic style, as if everything said is happening *right now*.

Comment: Unless it was just one fish, they would **become**

Comment: The sentence could also be interpreted as: **After millions of years fish began to grow teeth and (to) become like the fish of today.** - as though the second **to** had been elided.

Comment: Fish always take become (no s) as fish can be a plural or singular noun.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers so far are right. "Fish began to grow teeth and become like the fish of today" is grammatically correct.

There are two right answers depending on how you analyze it. The word 'and' may be joining two predicates, both belonging to the subject "fish" and both in the simple past tense:

> Fish **began to grow teeth** and **became like the fish of today.**

*Beginning to grow teeth* is an instantaneous event; to *begin* something is an act, not a process. If 'and' serves this role, we're looking a small part of the process of growing teeth and saying that it coincided with the entire process of becoming modern fish—that the moment the fish began to grow teeth, they completed their entire evolution. This isn't quite what we want to say.

We could also use 'and' to link two infinitives:

> Fish began to **grow teeth** and **become like the fish of today.**

In this form, the word "begin" applies to both acts, so the instantaneous moment which is the focus of the sentence is clearly only a part of the whole timeline. We're not saying anything about when the fish completed their evolution, just when it began.

To clear up any latent confusion regarding the tenses, the presence of 'began' as an auxiliary verb places the whole clause firmly in the past tense. "Become" is in the infinitive form (which looks a lot like the present simple) for the same reason that "grow" is, and for the same reason we don't say "I didn't did it."

Answer (score 0):

I think that neither is correct.

This is a matter of [parallelism](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/parallelism/):

Your first verb to describe fish is past tense - began, and the second verb is present. Therefore, this breaks the rule of parallelism.

Think of it this way. The fish from millions of years ago are not in the process of becoming like the fish of today. They already resemble the fish of today because the *became* the fish of today. Thus, I believe "became" is the correct verb.

Hope this helps.